# Possible to implement a conditional join clause - JOIN ON condition1 OR condition2?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to implement a conditional join clause in Entity Framework 6? Specifically, INNER JOIN ON (boolean condition1) OR (boolean condition2).

The code below works, but calls the database twice. Is it possible to consolidate it down into one call?

There is a foreign key relationship that ties FirmFeatures.FeatureId to Nullable FirmParameters.FeatureId

```
var dbContext = new MyEntities();
var feature = dbContext.FirmFeatures
    .Where(f => f.FeatureId == featureId)
    .First();

var parameters = dbContext.FirmParameters.AsQueryable();

parameters = feature.IsDbTable 
    ? parameters.Where(p => p.FeatureId == null) 
    : parameters.Where(p => p.FeatureId == featureId);

var list = parameters.ToList()
```

The SQL call would look something like:

```
SELECT feature.*, parameter.*
FROM [FirmFeature] AS feature
INNER JOIN [FirmParameter] AS parameter 
    ON (feature.IsDbTable = 0 AND feature.FeatureId = parameter.FeatureId) OR (feature.IsDbTable = 1 AND parameter.FeatureId IS NULL)
WHERE feature.[FeatureId] = 3
```

This leveraged database model first.

I'm new to the Entity Framework.

Edit2: I'm hoping to have both a features object and a parameters object loaded from the database as a result of this.

**EDIT: As requested, here are the models:**

```
{
    public FirmFeature()
    { this.FirmParameters = new HashSet<FirmParameter>(); }

    public byte FeatureId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDbTable { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<FirmParameter> FirmParameters { get; set; }
}

public partial class FirmParameter
{
    public byte ParameterId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> FeatureId { get; set; }
    ...    
    public virtual FirmFeature FirmFeature { get; set; }
    public virtual FirmParameter FirmParameter1 { get; set; }
    public virtual FirmParameter FirmParameter2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: could you share your c# db schema?

Comment: You need to show your entities. Also, there is no reason to add `AsQueryable()` after `dbContext.FirmParameters` which is already an `IQueryable`.

Comment: Without it, compilation fails. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<FirmParameter>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FirmParameter>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) @haim770

Comment: That's because later you're assigning the returned type of `Queryable.Where` to the same `parameters` variable. Although `AsQueryable()` solves the problem, it's intended for something else. A more readable approach would simply be `IQueryable<FirmParameter>  parameters = dbContext.FirmParameters;`

Comment: @Hoppe, Actually I was wrong assuming that this isn't a legitimate use of `AsQueryable()`, in fact, it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

try giving this a shot:

```
var isDbTableQuery = dbContext.FirmFeatures.Where(f => f.FeatureId == featureId && f.IsDbTable);
var parameters = dbContext.FirmParameters.Where(p => isDbTableQuery.Any() ? p.FeatureId == null : p.FeatureId == featureId);
var list = parameters.ToList();
```

Comment: This looks promising but how do I get the firmFeature? I.e. The following is null: var list = parameters.ToList(); var feature = list[0].FirmFeature;

Comment: was the firmfeature you had marked as IsDbTable?  if not I'd think the results would all have FirmFeature = null; you should be able to log the SQL that got generated and play around with it in sql manager to see what's going on

Comment: This still makes a second Db call to get the feature. Include didn't seem to work... Am I out of luck? @John

Comment: did you add a .tolist() or something else to execute the isDbTableQuery line early?  I have a call very similar to this in an application, and it correctly generates that first query as a subquery in a single call

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it right now, but if your only problem is the two round trips you can acomplish that using two LEFT joins, and selecting the appropriate source.

Something like:

```
var query = from feature in dbContext.FirmFeatures

            join parameter0 in dbContext.FirmParameters
              on new { IsDbTable = feature.IsDbTable, FeatureId = feature.FeatureId } equals new { IsDbTable = false, FeatureId = parameter0.FeatureId ?? 0 }
              into left_parameter_0
              from parameter_0 in left_parameter_0.DefaultIfEmpty()

            join parameter1 in dbContext.FirmParameters
              on new { IsDbTable = feature.IsDbTable, FeatureId = (byte?)null } equals new { IsDbTable = true, FeatureId = parameter1.FeatureId }
              into left_parameter_1
              from parameter_1 in left_parameter_1.DefaultIfEmpty()

select new { Feature = feature, Parameter = parameter_0 != null ? parameter_0 : parameter_1 };

var list = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Not sure how to get this to compile... 3 compilation errors. 2x: Expected contextual keyword 'equals'. 1x: semicolon expected

Comment: @Hoppe I was without compile at the time, I corrected the stated errors

Answer (score 0):

You can put the condition in the join statement. I'll do this in query syntax because that always reads far easier with joins:

```
var q = from f in dbContext.FirmFeatures
        where f.FeatureId == featureId
        join p in dbContext.FirmParameters on 
            (f.IsDbTable ? null : f.FeatureId) equals p.FeatureId
        select new { p, f };
```

Or simply:

```
var q2 = from p in dbContext.FirmParameters.Include(p => p.FirmFeature)
         where (p.FirmFeature.FeatureId == featureId && p.FirmFeature.IsDbTable)
            || p.Feature == null
         select p;
```

where you use `Include` to get `FirmParameters` having their `FirmFeature` references loaded (if there are any).

Comment: This only selects the parameters, but doesn't select the features

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = dbContext.FirmParameters
     .Where(p => (p.FirmFeature.FeatureId == featureId && p.FirmFeature.IsDbTable) ? 
            p.FeatureId == null : p.FeatureId == featureId)
     .ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

```
var list = dbContext.FirmParameters
           .Join(dbContext.FirmFeature, p.FeatureId, f.FeatureId, (p, f) => new { Parameter = p, Feature = f})
           .Where(@f => @f.Feature.FeatureId == featureId)
           .Where(@p => (@p.Feature.IsDbTable ? @p.Parameter.FeatureId == null : @p.Parameter.FeatureId == featureId))
           .Select(@x => new { Feature = @x.Feature, Parameter = @x.Parameter })
           .DefaultIfEmpty()
           .ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't retrieve any data from the FirmFeatures table. So that's a second call to the DB

Comment: @Hoppe , I think you are trying to accomplish an outer join, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3413732/1998487. I'll update my answer with an example.